# Transparent part of image in ImageView become black

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I have problem when displaying image with transparency in Android KitKat (Nexus 7), it is OK in nexus 4 (KitKat) and other previous Android OS, here the image:

[image]

and ImageView layout:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/avatar"
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
android:padding="3dp"
android:src="@drawable/icon_button_profile_new"
android:tag="@string/avatar" />
```

and here the screenshot when running on Nexus 7 (Android 4.4)
[image]

also, I use Picasso for download & caching image from the URL.

Comment: what is the color of your background ?

Comment: You can set your ImageView background color to transparent.

Comment: @ConnectinglifewithAndroid none, there is no background for the imageview as well as the layout container of the imageview

Comment: @SiddharthVyas I was try that, but it doesn't work

Comment: thats why you are seeing it black. set background color as desired. if you set android:background="@android:color/white" you will see white background

Comment: Seems like an issue with the bitmap format, maybe it is set to a format without alpha by Picasso or some other component?

Comment: @ConnectinglifewithAndroid I was try that as well, it is appear white in its padding, but not inside image itself

Comment: It is problem is cache bitmap, you save png image as JPEG "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);", but you need to save png image as png "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);"...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some trial: first I try using the image as resource drawable and it still happen (transparent part of the image become black), secondly I convert the image to png image and it is work, so the problem is in the file type (gif).
since in my real app the image obtained from server and I can't request image as always in png format, I use the solution from this link: [Transparent GIF in Android ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056050/transparent-gif-in-android-imageview)

it is simple for displaying only one image (like in my question) since I use Picasso I use target to erase black color from image avatar like this:

```
target = new Target() {         
@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {

}

@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 19/*Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT*/){
        Bitmap editedavatar = AndroidUtils.eraseColor(bitmap, -16777216);
        avatar.setImageBitmap(editedavatar);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
    avatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_profile_default);
```

where erase color is static method

```
public static Bitmap eraseColor(Bitmap src, int color) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap b = src.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    b.setHasAlpha(true);

    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
    src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        if (pixels[i] == color) {
            pixels[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    b.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    return b;
}
```

but since I use Picasso for displaying images in a listview,I impelements [Target](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html) in ViewHolder and it is work very well so far.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and solved it with that `b.setHasAlpha(true);`. That could be the critical line... Kudos!

Comment: this thing removed pure black but doesn't touch semi black

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/avatar"
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
android:padding="3dp"
android:src="@drawable/icon_button_profile_new"
android:background="#00000000"
android:tag="@string/avatar" />
```

Comment: this does not work Arslan, please verify your solution before posting.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @hakim : did u try with some other image