# Android 5: Icons turn black after keyboard disappears

Tags: java, android, icons

We have an Android application which works well on Android 4.1+ till Android 7.
Only in Android 5.0 and 5.1 we experience a difficult problem (on all devices + emulators).

The icons we use in our application turn completely black after hiding the software keyboard (when you are finished typing something in a textbox).
They stay black, even after restarting the application.

But after restarting the device (or closing the application by taskmanager), the icons are back normal (till you hide the keyboard again).

I don't find anything unusual in the code or icons and since it works in Android 4,6,7 it seems related to just Android 5.

Does someone has some idea at what the cause could be?
Disabling hardware-acceleration didn't have any effect.

[image: Normal]

[image: Black icons]

Answer (score 0):

This problem mainly occurs if you are using some other format of images  like `jpeg` , use only `png` images also you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20402227/6478047) answer