# Glide images shows Black background with transparent PNG image, Android

Tags: background, png, transparent

I am using glide to show URL images. when I have transparent PNG , it shows black backto ground. are there any way to adjust Glide to show those transparent images, or at least covert transparency to white ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WEBP_LOSSLESS it wont be transparent on API 29 and below.

```
    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder)
        val memoryCacheSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 100 // 100mb
        builder.setMemoryCache(LruResourceCache(memoryCacheSizeBytes.toLong()))
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions(context))

        builder.apply {
            requestOptions(context)
        }
    }

    private fun requestOptions(context: Context): RequestOptions {

        val compressFormat = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSY
        } else {
            Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
        }
        return RequestOptions()
            .signature(
                ObjectKey(
                    System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                )
            )
            .encodeFormat(compressFormat)
            .encodeQuality(80)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
            .skipMemoryCache(false)

    }
```

using .asBitmap() instead of .asDrawable() as well as  .transform(CenterInside()) with Landscapist and Glide causes this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issue recently, with glide version `4.14.2`. By borrowing the idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20402227/4326936)'s comment, I overcome this problem in glide with a customized bitmap transformation.

```kotlin
class HasAlpha: BitmapTransformation() {
    companion object {
        private const val ID = "com.bumptech.glide.transformations.HasAlpha"
        private val ID_BYTES = ID.toByteArray(CHARSET)
    }

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {
        messageDigest.update(ID_BYTES)
    }

    override fun transform(pool: BitmapPool, toTransform: Bitmap, outWidth: Int, outHeight: Int): Bitmap {
        toTransform.setHasAlpha(true)
        return toTransform
    }

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other is HasAlpha
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return ID.hashCode()
    }
}
```

Then apply the transformation above when loading image.

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).transform(HasAlpha()).into(imageView)
```

I am not sure it's a temporary bug in some versions of glide and not sure if it works on any kind of images with any kind of transparent channel, the image in my scenario has an fully transparent channel. Hopefully it would be helpful for anyone reach here.