# How to create a bitmap with transparent pixels in KitKat?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-4.4-kitkat, bitmapfactory

Starting with KitKat, a Bitmap created from a .gif by a BitmapFactory has black pixels where transparent ones are expected. Here's the code:

```
// Set up the BitmapFactory options
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

// Decode bitmap
b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(c.getInputStream(), null, options);
                
Log.d(TAG, "hasAlpha=" + b.hasAlpha());
Log.d(TAG, "color=" + b.getPixel(1,1));
```

If I run this in JellyBean, LogCat shows:

> hasAlpha=true
>
> color=0

But in KitKat, LogCat shows:

> hasAlpha=false
>
> color=-16777216

(-16777216 = android.graphics.Color.BLACK)

So, how do I get KitKat to display these pixels as transparent?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20057012/804773  -- Related answer