# Animated transparent GIF Image

Tags: android, xamarin

I have animated transparent gif image and need to display it in android. I tried Component GifImageView, everything is ok but background is black not transparent.

Thanks

```
 Stream input = Assets.Open("oie_2103618iUK1c2Pr.gif");
 byte[] bytes;
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
       input.CopyTo(ms);
       bytes = ms.ToArray();
 }

_gifImageView = new GifImageView(this);
_gifImageView.SetBytes(bytes);
_gifImageView.Background = new ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent);

LinearLayout giflayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.gif);              
giflayout.AddView(_gifImageView);
```

Comment: Transparency on GIFs is currently not supported and will show up black.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android

any other way ??

Answer (score 2):

try to add:

```
GifImageView.setBackgroung();
```

or read this: [Transparent GIF in Android ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056050/transparent-gif-in-android-imageview)

You can use another library, like [Android Gif Drawable](http://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) (GifImageView does not support transparent gifs), or set backround color (not transpatent) in gif, with gif editor.

Comment: Try set _gifImageView.Background = new  ColorDrawable(Color.Transparent); but does not work

Comment: just set background color same as your activity background for gif in gif editor for xamarin

Comment: You can try to make png files of gif, and than make android frame animation. Or just find another library

Comment: but you can compress png files.

Answer (score 0):

you cant set transparent background for gif image. Just remove it with online gif editor. There are a lot of them

Answer (score 0):

The current version of GifImageView doesn't have transparency changes that were just made a few days ago.  I was able to get it working by having my Activity inherit from GifImageView.IOnFrameAvailableListener and setting my gifImageView.OnFrameAvailableListener to the Activity(as seen [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GifImageView-Xamarin.Android)).  The last thing was to implement OnFrameAvailable in the Activity itself.

```
public Bitmap OnFrameAvailable(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            var newBitmap = bitmap.Copy (Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
            newBitmap.HasAlpha = true;

            var pixelArray = new int[bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height];
            bitmap.GetPixels (pixelArray, 0, bitmap.Width, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr <pixelArray.Count(); ctr++)
            {
                pixelArray[ctr] = pixelArray[ctr] == -16777216 ? 0 : pixelArray[ctr];
            }
            newBitmap.SetPixels (pixelArray, 0, bitmap.Width, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            return newBitmap;
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

This worked for me, hopefully it works for you too.  You may need to change -16777216 to -1 if you see white backgrounds.  Hopefully GifImageView gets updated soon, as this post-processing is not ideal.