# ImageView: black background with transparent gif

Tags: javascript, java, android, imageview, gif

I have problem with imageView:

I have this problem with  .JPEG too.

I switch image in imageview while program run, then i can't use static method. 
and I have picture from file drawable no from web.

> xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>
```

> call imageview:

```
potom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
potom.setImageResource(R.drawable.koc1);
```

koc1 is a .gif without background. And on mobile display have black square background, why?

But only on some android: on my phone (android 4.4) has black background. But on my friend s(android 5.0) it is OK. Please, whats the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: gif not supported directly in android, u should use third party component or png sequence file to show it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent GIF in Android ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056050/transparent-gif-in-android-imageview)

Comment: if i convert my gif picture to PNG bacgrount will be visible?

Comment: if switch .gif to JPEG its the same problem